# Javascript how to add target="_parent" in document.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
document.location.href="http://verttgrettest.com/testpaper.aspx?VideoId=1"
```

Javascript how to add target="_parent" in document.location.href

Comment: You want to open a new window/tab?

Comment: yup in new iframe window

Comment: You would change the src attribute of the iframe in that case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, the `.href` is literally just the URL you want to redirect to. You have to directly change the `.href` of the frame you want to target, not the href of the window/frame you're in e.g.

```
parent.document.location.href = 'http://...'
```

Comment: so no need of adding a targe="_parent"

Answer (score 3):

```
window.open(
  'http://verttgrettest.com/testpaper.aspx?VideoId=1',
  '_blank' 
);
```

Comment: your second parameter is way wrong https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open

Comment: @naveen according to the doc you linked, this is correct : _blank is a valid window name. The proposed solution works in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

//but popup blocker may block it

window.open('http://verttgrettest.com/testpaper.aspx?VideoId=1')

Comment: And the second parameter to `window.open` would be "_parent"

Answer (score 0):

I use the following codes:

```
if (parent)
    parent.document.location.href = '/iframe_parent';
else
    location.href = '/no_iframe';
```